# Как задать стили меню как в Android Studio и возможно ли это вообще?

Tags: javascript, electron

[image]

Как  задать стили меню как в Android Studio и возможно ли это вообще?

electron.js

Answer (score 3):

На сколько я знаю, да. В [GitHub Desktop](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/) (он тоже написан на Electron) так сделано:

[image: Скриншот]

На сколько я понимаю, они убрали стандартные контролы а потом сверстали свои, которые выглядят так же.

Код можно найти здесь: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/tree/development/app/src/ui/window